# osmdroid - Bundle Offline Map Tiles

Tags: java, android, dictionary, osmdroid

I've seen posts and tutorials about how to include offline map tiles by adding them to the SD card but is there a way in which these tiles can be bundled within the APK?

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility to place map tiles into app directly. From my point of view, best should be store tiles in **SQLite database** in assets forlder. After your app starts, you should copy this DB from assets and use it. Maybe even better should be to prepare this SQLite map database somewhere on your server and when app starts, you should simply download it.

How to read data from assets folder is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html)
I also suggest to check some topics, where you may read about common way how map apps store map tiles in database. One of commonly used formats is [MBT](https://www.mapbox.com/developers/mbtiles/)